# Как передать методу аргументы в произвольном порядке?

Tags: c#

Как передать методу аргументы в произвольном порядке?

Comment: А зачем вам это?

Comment: Используя их имена? `myMethod(value2: "4", value1: "1");`

Comment: без использования имени

Comment: Тогда см. пункт 1: *А зачем вам это?*

Comment: [Named and Optional parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: если без использования имени - то только используя `params object[]` но при этом в теле метода соответственно придется самому разбираться где какой параметр

Comment: @АлександрПузанов: А как без имён тогда компилятор поймёт, какой из них какой? Например, если у вас два целочисленных аргумента.

Comment: @VladD, я выше пример привел :) и очевидно - никак :)

Comment: @Grundy: Ну ладно, ждём, пока ТС прочитает комментарии и дополнит вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте именованные аргументы.

```
new string('A', 2);
```

равносильно

```
new string(count: 2, c: 'A');
```

Comment: уже выяснилось что он хочет без имен :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Пусть допишет тогда в вопрос :)